# What is the maximum height a settlement can reach in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

See title. Obviously the maximum base is determined by the perimeter, but the maximum height is not specified.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Yes there is and it differs between each settlement](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/3sf2th/psa_settlements_have_a_maximum_build_height/). The settlement boundaries are a box extending upwards towards the skybox but the ground height varies between settlements.

Crediting the above link, here are some examples;

- Sanctuary - 6 stories
- Tenpines - 3 stories (From the highest point)
- Starlight - 9 stories
- Greentop Nursery - 7 stories (From the level of the house)

...where "stories" is defined as a wall with a roof (with the next story being another wall on top with another roof, etc)

Comment: Interesting! See my answer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/244013/what-is-the-maximum-height-a-settlement-can-reach-in-fallout-4/244015#244015 . 

This implies settlements build-able space is volume based. I say this because RRTS has a very small x/y space, but a large z component.

Comment: Either that or because RRTS is significantly lower down than Sanctuary, which makes sense in terms of the testing done at Greentop Nursery - the volume idea would make sense for Starlight drive in though. Maybe needs more testing?

Comment: Probably, haha. I honestly didn't expect that anyone had done any testing at all. If I had a PC version of the game, I'd throw together a mod to measure maximum build volume, but alas, I'm on a PS4

Comment: More settlement heights here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/3sf2th/psa_settlements_have_a_maximum_build_height/

Comment: A nearly complete list per settlement of maximum floors, triangles and draw limitations can be [found here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/311061/which-settlements-allow-the-largest-number-of-triangles-and-draw-size?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 2):

20 stories at Abernathy farm. I play on Xbox one. I used the reset settlement size glitch.

Comment: I wouldn't really say using a glitch is a legitimate answer. The second a patch is released that fixed this glitch renders the answer obsolete.

Comment: This answer is correct. [Abernathy Farm can go up to 19~20 floors, and that's the *tallest* you can go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/311061/which-settlements-allow-the-largest-number-of-triangles-and-draw-size) (the tallest structure you can build, not the *highest*; height is arbitrary). OP needed the settlement resize just to be able to build enough crap to go that high.

Answer (score 2):

Anything above the fifth floor kicks you out of build mode in Sanctuary. Also, I've noticed that even using the weapons trick to add more settlement size to the meter is okay to do but by the end of the second go round on using the trick, the graphics start getting a little twitchy. Nothing major but I wouldn't suggest pushing past using the trick more than twice but that is filling up the meter, clearing it completely and repeating the process once the meter fills up again. This will not add to your build height as that as set by a different limit. However, you can build one massive facility. So, long as you take it easy on the decorations and don't waste time with clutter, you will be able to make a serious fortress.

Answer (score 1):

BOS Airport: 5-6 floors
Sanctuary: 5-6 floors
Warwick Homestead: 11+ floors (I Never reached the top)
Vault 88: 5 floors
Hanged Man's Alley: 2 floors

Answer (score 0):

Via in-game testing (PS4), the maximum build-able height is 12+1 floors. This number was found by building shack stairs up from the ground at Red Rocket Truck Stop, connected to each other. At 12 stories, additional rooms/flooring can be added in the x/y planes. This includes another shack staircase.

Adding that last staircase is it though; you can't build off its landing on the top.

Comment: The maximum ---buildable height--- *number of floors* by building shack stairs up from the ground at Red Rocket Truck Stop (!) is 12+1 floors. At Abernathy farm it's upwards of 20.