# Which settlements allow the largest number of triangles and draw size?

Tags: fallout-4

I am wondering which settlements have the **biggest item size** to build in.
Since [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/244001/what-contributes-to-the-settlement-size-limit) determines that the size is calculated in polygons, <strike>I'm wondering if this amount is the same for every settlement or not?</strike>

In the answer it is said:

> The size limit and current size used are actually attributes against the workbench in the settlement itself and differ between settlements.

I would still like to know what that size is for some of the bigger settlements to see how much difference there is between them.
I am on Xbox, so I cannot use console commands myself to check anything.

---

> Just to clarify: I am not talking about the size of the area itself. I
> am talking about the polygon count for the size bar that shows in the workshop mode while
> building things.

Comment: I would imagine so since this is based on performance parameters, but can't say for certain.

Comment: So are you asking which settlement has the largest "Size Bar" when you first settle it or which settlement has the largest build area in general?  The first sentence and title of your question seems to be different that your clarification part at the end of your question.

Comment: @TimmyJim I mean how many items can be placed before the bar is full. Example; you can place 1000 generators in settlement A and the size bar is full. You can place 1001 generators in settlement B; Settlement B is larger then A

Comment: @Vemonus Uhm, thx but that's the same question as I linked in my question...

Comment: @Vahx my bad. The top answer tells you that settlements have different build sizes based on their actual size though, which would imply that Spectacle Island has the largest build space.

Comment: @Vemonus Hm, true, still hoping someone will give some numbers from checking. Even if its just to see how much of a difference there is

Comment: I agree with Vemonous. I have built a whole city on spectacle island. Still havent run out of building room or bar space... now if only the population would match the scale

Comment: @KaiQing - I recommend the mods *More Settlers* and *Better Settlers*. The problem is that your computer needs to match the scale. But on a console, your millage *won't* vary... These limits are induced specifically because of the cross-platform compatibility requirements of unmodifiable hardware, on which it has been extensively tested.

Comment: Well, I'm on ps4. I dont know if mods are available and it's really a non issue anymore. I've grown to a point where nothing is a challenge anymore so building was just for fun. Good to know that exists for PCs though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Settlement Sizes in Triangles and Floors](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/492378806377777707/) –Steam Discussions

```
Abernathy Farm
    Min: 220,260
    Max: 2,000,000
    Free: 1,779,740
    Floors: 19
Boston Airport
    Min:
    Max:
    Free:
    Floors:
Bunker Hill
    Min:
    Max:
    Free:
    Floors:
The Castle
    Min: 427,250
    Max: 1,000,000
    Free: 572,750
    Floors: 7
Coastal Cottage
    Min: 26,678
    Max: 1,000,000
    Free: 973,322
    Floors: 6
Country Crossing
    Min: 87,458
    Max: 1,000,000
    Free: 912,542
    Floors: 10
Covenant
    Min: 115,923
    Max: 1,000,000
    Free: 884,077
    Floors: 1
Croup Manor
    Min: 104,420
    Max: 1,000,000
    Free: 895,580
    Floors: 10
Egret Tours Marina
    Min: 152,944
    Max: 1,200,000
    Free: 1,047,056
    Floors: 5
Finch Farm
    Min: 141,549
    Max: 1,500,000
    Free: 1,358,451
    Floors: 12
Graygarden
    Min: 189,711
    Max: 1,800,000
    Free: 1,610,289
    Floors: 9
Greentop Nursery
    Min: 110,467
    Max: 1,200,000
    Free: 1,089,533
    Floors: 6
Hangman's Alley
    Min: 54,527
    Max: 1,000,000
    Free: 945,473
    Floors: 3
Home Plate
    Min:
    Max:
    Free:
    Floors:
Jamaica Plain
    Min: 0
    Max: 500,000
    Free: 500,000
    Floors: 4
Kingsport Lighthouse
    Min: 38,668
    Max: 1,500,000
    Free: 1,461,332
    Floors: 10
Murkwater Construction Site
    Min: 151,220
    Max: 1,000,000
    Free: 848,780
    Floors: 6
Nordhagen Beach
    Min: 84,130
    Max: 1,250,000
    Free: 1,165,870
    Floors: 9
Oberland Station
    Min: 78,931
    Max: 1,000,000
    Free: 921,069
    Floors: 5
Outpost Zimonja
    Min: 56,356
    Max: 1,000,000
    Free: 943,644
    Floors: 10
Red Rocket Truck Stop
    Min: 0
    Max: 1,000,000
    Free: 1,000,000
    Floors: 10
Sanctuary Hills
    Min: 16,297
    Max: 3,000,000
    Free: 2,983,703
    Floors: 4
The Slog
    Min: 120,040
    Max: 1,500,000
    Free: 1,379,960
    Floors: 10
Somerville Place
    Min: 110,401
    Max: 1,500,000
    Free: 1,389,599
    Floors: 9
Spectacle Island
    Min: 411,124
    Max: 5,000,000
    Free: 4,588,876
    Floors: 8
Starlight Drive In
    Min: 108,466
    Max: 1,500,000
    Free: 1,391,534
    Floors: 8
Sunshine Tidings Co-Op
    Min: 137,781
    Max: 1,250,000
    Free: 1,112,219
    Floors: 10
Taffington Boathouse
    Min: 88,763
    Max: 1,000,000
    Free: 911,237
    Floors: 7
Tenpines Bluff
    Min: 7,531
    Max: 1,000,000
    Free: 992,469
    Floors: 3
Warwick Homestead
    Min: 210,074
    Max: 1,500,000
    Free: 1,289,926
    Floors: 8
```

---

[Basic Overview of Settlement Build Limits, Triangles, and Draws](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/350542145702664401/) –Steam Discussions

> I put this together because I could not find something similar and it took me a while learn this. I hope it helps someone.
>
> Triangles: Every object in the game is made from a mesh of connected triangles. When the computer needs to create objects it uses ".nif" files (a nif file contains more than just mesh information, but that is another subject). A cube must have at least two triangles per face (12 triangles minimum). A sphere will have many more triangles, depending on how smooth it needs to appear.
>
> Individual settlements have a game-preset limit on the number of allowed triangles (settlement limits differ). The limit can be raised, but more computer resources may be needed - and every computer is different.
>
> Draws: When the game creates one mesh from the workshop it is using one "draw". An individual nif file can have multiple meshes, so multiple draws may be used.
>
> Individual settlements have a game-preset limit on the number of allowed draws (settlement limits differ). The limit can be raised, but more computer resources may be needed - and every computer is different.
>
> Example:
>   The standard concrete foundation block with wood floor from the workbench begins with a file named ShackMidFloor01Foundation.nif
>
> One ShackMidFloor01Foundation.nif contains three meshes and therefore requires three draws The three meshes are for the concrete portion, the wood sides above the concrete, and the wood floor planks.
>
> One ShackMidFloor01Foundation.nif contains 96 triangles. 36 are for the concrete portion, 48 are for the wood sides above the concrete, and 12 are for the wood floor planks.
>
> The settlement of Sanctuary is setup to allow 3,000,000 triangles. So, does that mean you can theoretically build 31,250 ShackMidFloor01Foundation.nifs? NO! But why? You see, the workbench in the settlement of Sanctuary is also setup to cease new construction at 3,000 draws - and each ShackMidFloor01Foundation.nif uses three draws. So, does that mean you can theoretically only add 1,000 ShackMidFloor01Foundation.nifs - even though you are well below the triangle limit? YES!
>
> Q & A
>
> Q: So, that settlement size bar in the upper right corner that gets bigger it a function of the draw count, not the triangle count?
>   A: YES!
>
> Q: The settlement size bar gets smaller when I scrap settlement items that are not created in the workbench. It seems like a player could get around the draw count by just traveling around outside the settlement and collecting a bunch of junk, dropping the junk from the Pip-Boy onto the ground of the settlement, and scrap it. Since the "outside" junk can be scrapped - it must be related to the workbench, even though it was not originally built in the settlement. Can I reduce a settlement draw count for scrapping something I bring in from outside the settlement without using a mod?
>   A: YES!

Comment: Spectacle Island has 1,605,173 *more* free tangles than the penultimately sized settlement of Sanctuary, a number which is equivalent to the size of your average settlement in free triangles.

Comment: I didn't actually do the math. It's somewhere between *the equivalent* and *friggin' huge by at least twice*.

Comment: Pretty much what i was looking for, thank you very much

Comment: TIL: Abernathy Farm can go up to 19~20 floors, and that's the [tallest you can go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/249017/77980).

Comment: That is a very nice list.